# Generic isomorphism between sums and heterogeneous sums

Tags: haskell, isomorphism, generics-sop

Is there a Haskell library providing (or assisting in writing) generic isomorphism between a sum type and an associated heterogenous sum type?

Take the following sum type,

```hs
data TR = TR_Index | TR_Inner R
```

Now we associate it with a heterogenous sum [`NS I xs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP.html#t:NS) (where the 'xs' is defined by a type-class; see `MotleyRouteSubRoutes` below). And then define a isomorphism to convert back and forth:

```hs
instance MotleyRoute TR where
  -- `SingletonRoute s` is isomorphic to `()`
  -- `PrefixedRoute s r` is isomorphic to `Const r s`
  type MotleyRouteSubRoutes TR = 
    '[ SingletonRoute "index.html"
     , PrefixedRoute "inner" R
     ]
  motleyRouteIso =
    iso
      ( \case
          TR_Index -> Z $ I SingletonRoute
          TR_Inner r -> S $ Z $ I $ PrefixedRoute r
      )
      ( \case
          Z (I SingletonRoute) -> TR_Index
          S (Z (I (PrefixedRoute r))) -> TR_Inner r
          S (S x) -> case x of {}
      )
```

My goal here is to write `motleyRouteIso` generically (as well as define `MotleyRouteSubRoutes` generically, but that maybe outside the scope here). I was going to do it from scratch using `generics-sop`, but I wonder if there already is a library that does this for me. `generic-optics` provides a [`IsList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-optics-2.2.1.0/docs/Data-Generics-Product-HList.html) but that works for products not sums.

(For full context, see [this PR](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/93))

Comment: is `Coercible` relevant here?

Comment: `Coercible` is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen no answer on this so far I'll assume for the moment no such prebuilt solution exists. So here's an approach I went with based on `generics-sop`.

### `RGeneric`

First I added a `RGeneric` type-class to narrow the case where a route ADT can have constructors with 0 or 1 product only:

```hs
-- | Like `Generic` but for Route types only.
class RGeneric r where
  type RCode r :: [Type]
  rfrom :: r -> NS I (RCode r)
  rto :: NS I (RCode r) -> r
```

The implementation of this instance is fairly straightforward using `generics-sop`. You can [see it here](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/93/commits/9b9ca3712cda6051fcfa493c307838e5edc89882) (the `RouteNP` constraint captures the expected "shape" of route types we are interested in).

### Introduce `Coercible` for heavy-lifting

Note that the individual types in `MotleyRouteSubRoutes` are more or less coercible to the route type constructors. So I used that knowledge to "eliminate" the specific types from the equation thus getting one large step closer to a generic implementation. Specifically:

```
@@ -95,12 +95,12 @@ instance MotleyRoute TR where
   motleyRouteIso =
     iso
       ( \case
-          TR_Index -> Z $ I SingletonRoute
-          TR_Inner r -> S $ Z $ I $ PrefixedRoute r
+          TR_Index -> Z $ coerce ()
+          TR_Inner r -> S $ Z $ coerce r
       )
       ( \case
-          Z (I SingletonRoute) -> TR_Index
-          S (Z (I (PrefixedRoute r))) -> TR_Inner r
+          Z (I (coerce -> ())) -> TR_Index
+          S (Z r) -> TR_Inner $ coerce r
           S (S x) -> case x of {}
       )
```

Notice how in the new version there is no reference to `SingletonRoute` or `PrefixedRoute`.

[Full diff here](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/93/commits/f9c7908bf8b0a622b18ea34eea41b258d55596ff).

### Generic Iso

With this place, it is now pretty straightforward to generically implement `motleyRouteIso` using [`trans_NS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP-NS.html#v:trans_NS) because the `Coercible` constraint does all the heavy lifting for us, with `RGeneric` abstracting out dealing with expected 'shape' of the route type. It looks like this:

```hs
-- Rough code (leaving out the constraints)
gmotleyRouteIso =
  iso (gtoMotley @r . rfrom) (rto . gfromMotley @r)
  where 
     gtoMotley = trans_NS (Proxy @Coercible) coerce
     gfromMotley = trans_NS (Proxy @Coercible) coerce
```

The [change for this is here](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/93/commits/e458f6228c00a9b32ac92119f4e47c673e2ef04f).