# `Coercible` for uni-constructor types and `()`

Tags: haskell, coercion

This type can be coerced to `()`:

```hs
newtype Foo = Foo ()
f :: Foo -> ()
f = coerce
```

But the following cannot:

```hs
data Foo = Foo
f :: Foo -> ()
f = coerce  -- Fails: Couldn't match representation of type ‘Foo’ with that of ‘()’
```

GHC says,

```
    • Couldn't match representation of type ‘Foo’ with that of ‘()’
        arising from a use of ‘coerce’
    • In the expression: coerce
      In an equation for ‘f’: f = coerce
   |
69 | f = coerce
```

Is there a way to make that second `Foo` coercible to `()`? They are both isomorphic after all. Failing this, what is the way to automatically create these isomorphisms? For a larger context, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72746662/55246) (where the constructor's product type is coercible to the `NS`'s type-level list element type).

### @Iceland_Jack's suggestion

Trying Jack's suggestion in comments to go via generic `Rep`:

```hs
class (GHC.Generic a, GHC.Generic b, Coercible (GHC.Rep a ()) (GHC.Rep b ())) => HasSameRep a b where
  coerceViaRep :: I a -> I b

instance
  ( Generic a
  , Generic b
  , Coercible (GHC.Rep a ()) (GHC.Rep b ())
  ) =>
  HasSameRep a b
  where
  coerceViaRep = I . GHC.to @_ @() . coerce . GHC.from @_ @() . unI

data T = T

proof :: T -> ()
proof = unI . coerceViaRep . I
```

This fails, however:

```
src/Ema/Route/Generic/Sub.hs:122:15-26: error:
    • Couldn't match representation of type: GHC.U1 @Type ()
                               with that of: GHC.Rep T ()
        arising from a use of ‘coerceViaRep’
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘coerceViaRep’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘coerceViaRep . I’
      In the expression: unI . coerceViaRep . I
    |
122 | proof = unI . coerceViaRep . I
```

It doesn't look like the underlying generic representation is in fact equal?

Comment: Coercion isn't just about isomorphism, but bit for bit equality in the runtime representation.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a type class that is like `Coercible` but doesn't care about equality of runtime representation? That's probably what I want.

Comment: Yes, if the types are generic you can roundtrip through the generic representation. For example `Rep ()` and `Rep Foo` (from `GHC.Generics`) have different metadata but their generic representations are equal at runtime. With the assumption `Coercible (Rep a ()) (Rep b ())` you can travel: `a` --from-> `Rep a ()` --coerce-> `Rep b ()` --to-> `b`.

Comment: @Iceland_jack That's interesting, but it doesn't seem to be true? See my updated question.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar Uh, you didn't derive `Generic` for `T`. That's why the error message contains the suspiciously stuck type family application `Rep T ()`, because that's not been defined. If you write `data T = T deriving Generic` instead then the `Generic`-based solution works. (Also, I am mystified what good the `I`s are doing here.)

Comment: Try `deriving stock Generic` ;) I make this error all the time. There is no reason to use identity constructors or making your own type class for this, you can define ``coerceViaRep :: Generic a => Generic b => Rep a () `Coercible` Rep b () => a -> b; coerceViaRep = to @_ @() . coerce . from @_ @()`` as a top-level function where `proof = coerceViaRep @T @()`.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right! By the way, I used `I` (and a typeclass) only so it can be used in `generics-sop` code.

Comment: One thing I do not understand is why is the error message on `proof` not spotting the lack of `Generic` instance? Shouldn't it say `No instance 'Generic T'` or some such thing? The `HasSameRep` class afterall has that constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying @Iceland_Jack's suggestion (also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385077/55246)) in the comments here's what I came up with:

```hs
{- | Types `a` and `b` are isomorphic via their generic representation

  Unlike `Coercible` this constraint does not require that the two types have
  identical *runtime* representation. For example, `data Foo = Foo` is not
  coercible to `()` (they have different runtime representations), but they are
  both isomorphic via their generic representation.
-}
class (Generic a, Generic b, GHC.Rep a () `Coercible` GHC.Rep b ()) => GIsomorphic a b where
  giso :: Iso' a b

instance (Generic a, Generic b, GHC.Rep a () `Coercible` GHC.Rep b ()) => GIsomorphic a b where
  giso =
    iso
      (GHC.to @b @() . coerce . GHC.from @a @())
      (GHC.to @a @() . coerce . GHC.from @b @())

data T (s :: Symbol) = T
  deriving stock (Generic)

proof :: T "foo" -> ()
proof = view giso
```

You could eliminate the typeclass and define `giso` as a top-level function, but in my case I need a constraint for use with `generics-sop`'s `trans_NS`. https://github.com/EmaApps/ema/pull/81/commits/760fd793104ae4235055ad49c94ac014f014496e